# SQL Server Management Studio - How to model this database constraint in a Database Diagram

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, relational-database, constraints

I have a table named Communications which contain a user's contact numbers. This can either be a Home, Mobile or Fax number. I'm storing them all in one table and identifying them using a Type column. (0 = Home, 1 = Mobile, 2 = Fax). Communications table has a foreign key UserId which maps to my Users table to show User to Number relation. I want to have a constraint so that each user can only have at most one of each Type of number. What would be the best way to model this?

I'm using Database Diagram in SQL Server Manager Studio 2008 and would like a GUI-ish answer as opposed to SQL query if possible.

Comment: I don't think database diagrams have any way of allowing you to click and drag to create some type of constraint like this. They're designed to show the general set of tables and their relationships, not every single aspect of the data model. Anyway it sounds like you have the relationship backward - if a user can only have one communication type, why doesn't the user table have a foreign key to the communications table's type column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I meant that a user can have one of each type. So a user can have at most 1 home phone, 1 mobile phone, 1 fax; but not 2 home phones, 5 mobile phones, 10 fax. They may also have 0.

On a different note, how would I model such a constraint using SQL queries in SSMS?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a NumberType table, containing the values 0,1,2 as primary key in column NumberType, and add a foreign key from table Communications.NumberType to NumberType.NumberType. This way table Comunications will only be able to contain values 0,1,2 (or whatever NumberTypes you define).

Then you add a primary key (or unique index, if you want some other primary key) to table Communications on columns NumberType and UserId. This makes sure that each user may only have one number of each kind.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use composite key `{UserID, NumberType}`

[image]

---

It also a good idea to keep `{UserID, PhoneNo}` unique and to make sure that a phone number is of one type only; while allowing for more than one user to have the same phone number, say home phone for a family. In that case you can try something like this

[image]

Note: implement `AK` (alternate key) as a unique index.